# Show that these two systems of cyclic equations must have the same solution.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math

Let $x_i>0$ for all $i$. It can be shown that $$2+x_i +x_j +x_k +x_i x_j x_k\geq 2(\sqrt{x_i x_j}+\sqrt{x_i x_k}+\sqrt{x_j x_k})$$ and we have equality only when $x_i=x_j=x_k=1$.

Consider the following cylic system of equations:

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{24} (2 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_2 x_3 x_4) &+ \frac{1}{6} \left(-\frac{x_2}{2 \sqrt{x_1 x_2}} - \frac{x_3}{2 \sqrt{x_1 x_3}} - \frac{x_4}{2 \sqrt{x_1 x_4}}\right) = 0, \\
\frac{1}{24} (2 + x_1 + x_3 + x_4 + x_1 x_3 x_4) &+ \frac{1}{6} \left(-\frac{x_1}{2 \sqrt{x_1 x_2}} - \frac{x_3}{2 \sqrt{x_2 x_3}} - \frac{x_4}{2 \sqrt{x_2 x_4}}\right) = 0, \\
\frac{1}{24} (2 + x_1 + x_2 + x_4 + x_1 x_2 x_4) &+ \frac{1}{6} \left(-\frac{x_1}{2 \sqrt{x_1 x_3}} - \frac{x_2}{2 \sqrt{x_2 x_3}} - \frac{x_4}{2 \sqrt{x_3 x_4}}\right) = 0, \\
\frac{1}{24} (2 + x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_1 x_2 x_3) &+ \frac{1}{6} \left(-\frac{x_1}{2 \sqrt{x_1 x_4}} - \frac{x_2}{2 \sqrt{x_2 x_4}} - \frac{x_3}{2 \sqrt{x_3 x_4}}\right) = 0.
\end{align}

The solution of this system of equations is $x_1=x_2=x_3=x_4=1$.

Now consider the following cyclic system of equations:

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{12} (\sqrt{x_2 x_3}+\sqrt{x_2 x_4}+\sqrt{x_3 x_4}) &+ \frac{1}{6} \left(-\frac{x_2}{2 \sqrt{x_1 x_2}} - \frac{x_3}{2 \sqrt{x_1 x_3}} - \frac{x_4}{2 \sqrt{x_1 x_4}}\right) = 0, \\
\frac{1}{12} (\sqrt{x_1 x_3}+\sqrt{x_1 x_4}+\sqrt{x_3 x_4}) &+ \frac{1}{6} \left(-\frac{x_1}{2 \sqrt{x_1 x_2}} - \frac{x_3}{2 \sqrt{x_2 x_3}} - \frac{x_4}{2 \sqrt{x_2 x_4}}\right) = 0, \\
\frac{1}{12} (\sqrt{x_1 x_2}+\sqrt{x_1 x_4}+\sqrt{x_2 x_4}) &+ \frac{1}{6} \left(-\frac{x_1}{2 \sqrt{x_1 x_3}} - \frac{x_2}{2 \sqrt{x_2 x_3}} - \frac{x_4}{2 \sqrt{x_3 x_4}}\right) = 0, \\
\frac{1}{12} (\sqrt{x_1 x_2}+\sqrt{x_1 x_3}+\sqrt{x_2 x_3}) &+ \frac{1}{6} \left(-\frac{x_1}{2 \sqrt{x_1 x_4}} - \frac{x_2}{2 \sqrt{x_2 x_4}} - \frac{x_3}{2 \sqrt{x_3 x_4}}\right) = 0.
\end{align}

This system of equations also has only one solution, which is $x_1=x_2=x_3=x_4=1$.

Is there a way to see that the two system of equations must have the same solution? Note that I am not looking for an argument that directly calculates the solutions to the two systems of equations.

Comment: The two systems of equations, denoted by $(A)$ and $(B)$, have the same solutions if and only if any equation of $(A)$ can be deduced from the system of equations $(B)$ and vice versa.

Comment: @NN2- That's not necessarily true. For example, $y+x=0, y-x=0$ and $y-x^2=0, y+x^6=0$ also have the same solution $(0,0)$, although one system of equations cannot be deduced from the other.

Comment: In your example, tell me which equation cannot be deduced from the other system of equations?

Comment: @NN2- Ah I suppose you mean we can deduce $y-x^2$ from $y\pm x=0$. How about $y-x^8=0,y+x^6=0$?

Comment: @NN2- In general, you can have very different functions intersect at the same point. For example, you also have $y=e^{|x|}-1,y=\sin x$ also intersect only at $(0,0)$. I'm sure you'll agree that these equations cannot be derived from $y\pm x=0$.